# What's required to configure Ubuntu to use a specific DNS server?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, bind

I've setup two Amazon EC2 instances, both running Ubuntu Server.  One is configured as a DNS server running bind9, which will be used to allow EC2 instances to communicate with each other based on hostname rather than IP, since their private IPs may change.

I think I have the DNS server setup correctly.  I want to use the second EC2 instance to test the DNS server.

Using Webmin, I've added the DNS server's private IP to the client's DNS Servers list and added the domain to the Search Domains list.  I did have to edit **/etc/dhcp3/dhclint.conf** to make my changes stick.

After reboot, I expected I'd be able to ping or nslookup the DNS server from the test client, but it can't seem to find the server.  Is there something I'm missing?

> What's required to configure an Ubuntu
>   client to use a DNS server?

I just want to make sure I'm not missing something before I assume the server's the problem.

Comment: alvosu was correct, /etc/resolv.conf is all that's required.  I was IP-restricting access to the EC2 instances using the Security Groups, which allowed my local machine to communicate with them, but prevented them from communicating with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dhclient update /etc/resolv.conf. [Solution](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/).